# Opening a folder path but only knowing part of the folder name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to make  macro to open a  folder based on a file name that is within a cell, this is the code that i have so far

```
Sub OpenFolder()

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim JobNumber As String
    Dim JobYearLeft As String
    Dim JobYear As String
    Dim FolderNumber As String
    Dim i As Integer

    JobNumber = Right(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - 3)
    JobYearLeft = Right(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - 1)
    JobYear = Left(JobYearLeft, Len(JobYearLeft) - 4)

    i = CInt(JobNumber)

    Select Case i
    Case 0 To 500
        FolderNumber = "0001_0500"
    Case 500 To 1000
        FolderNumber = "0501_1000"
    Case 1000 To 1500
        FolderNumber = "1001_1500"
    Case 1500 To 2000
        FolderNumber = "1501_2000"
    End Select

    If (JobYear = 17) Then
        MyFolder = "M:\2017\" & FolderNumber & "\"
    Else
        MyFolder = "M:\2016\" & FolderNumber & "\"
    End If

    MyFolder = Replace(MyFolder, " ", "")
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink MyFolder

    MsgBox (MyFolder)
    MsgBox (i)
    MsgBox (JobNumber)
    MsgBox (FolderNumber)

End Sub
```

Say that my folder path is `M:\2017\1501_2000\V171504******\`
Where `****` denotes the parts that are unknown and the length of that string isn't constant and `V171504` is the value that is contained on cell "A1" (The MsgBox are for my testing to know if im getting the right values).

Edit, here is the Dir that I've tried

```
FindFirstFile = Dir$(MyFolder & "*" & "/")

If (FindFirstFile <> "") Then
    FindFirstFile = Replace(FindFirstFile, " ", "")
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FindFirstFile
Else

End If
```

Here is overall what has been happening

```
Sub OpenFolder()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim JobNumber As String
Dim JobYearLeft As String
Dim JobYear As String
Dim FolderNumber As String
Dim i As Integer

JobNumber = Right(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - 3)
JobYearLeft = Right(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - 1)
JobYear = Left(JobYearLeft, Len(JobYearLeft) - 4)

i = CInt(JobNumber)

Select Case i
    Case 0 To 500
    FolderNumber = "0001_0500"
        Case 500 To 1000
        FolderNumber = "0501_1000"
            Case 1000 To 1500
            FolderNumber = "1001_1500"
                Case 1500 To 2000
                FolderNumber = "1501_2000"
End Select

If (JobYear = 17) Then
    MyFolder = "M:\2017\" & FolderNumber & "\"
    Else
        MyFolder = "M:\2016\" & FolderNumber & "\"
End If

MyFolder = Replace(MyFolder, " ", "")

Dim file As String
    file = Dir$(MyFolder & Range("A1").Value & "*" & "/")

If (Len(file) > 0) Then
 MsgBox "found" & file
 file = Dir$()
 ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink file
End If
```

I am currently getting a error at

```
file = Dir$(MyFolder & Range("A1").Value & "*" & "\")
```

For Run-time Error '52'
Bad file name or number

Comment: Have you looked at [`DIR Function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dir-function)? Give it a try and if you have issues, then post here.

Comment: I had this but it doesnt seem to work    

FindFirstFile = Dir$(MyFolder & "*" & "/")
    
    If (FindFirstFile <> "") Then
        FindFirstFile = Replace(FindFirstFile, " ", "")
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FindFirstFile
    Else

    End If

Comment: Can you add it instead in your question?

Comment: Following your example above, the link it's trying to open (`MyFolder`) is `M:\2017\1501_2000\`. What are you expecting `MyFolder` to contain?

Comment: So basically I only know the first part of the folder name and I want to open a the folder containing the sting on cell A1

Comment: @L42 I updated my code and took your advice, but i seem to be hitting a brick wall with the Dir Function

Answer (score 0):

I found how to make it work

```
Sub OpenFolder()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim JobNumber As String
Dim JobYearLeft As String
Dim JobYear As String
Dim FolderNumber As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim FirstFolder As String

JobNumber = Right(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - 3)
JobYearLeft = Right(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - 1)
JobYear = Left(JobYearLeft, Len(JobYearLeft) - 4)

i = CInt(JobNumber)

Select Case i
    Case 0 To 500
    FolderNumber = "0001_0500"
        Case 500 To 1000
        FolderNumber = "0501_1000"
            Case 1000 To 1500
            FolderNumber = "1001_1500"
                Case 1500 To 2000
                FolderNumber = "1501_2000"
End Select


If (JobYear = 17) Then
    FirstFolder = "M:\2017\" & FolderNumber & "\" '& Range("A1").Value & "*" & "\"
    Else
        MyFolder = "M:\2016\" & FolderNumber & "\" '& Range("A1").Value & "*" & "\"
End If

If (JobYear = 17) Then
    MyFolder = "M:\2017\" & FolderNumber & "\" & Range("A1").Value & "*" '& "\"
    Else
        MyFolder = "M:\2016\" & FolderNumber & "\" & Range("A1").Value & "*" '& "\"
End If

MyFolder = Replace(MyFolder, " ", "")

Dim OpenThisFolder As String
Dim GoToFolder As String

MyFolder = Dir(MyFolder, vbDirectory)

GoToFolder = FirstFolder & MyFolder & "\"
GoToFolder = Replace(GoToFolder, " ", "")
```

Ended up using vbdirectory